# Disconnected Jenkins agents using websocket

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to move my build agents to use the websocket protocol instead of JNLP. It seems very close but my agents are showing as disconnected.

If I look at the log for the agent it says:

```
Inbound agent connected from x.x.x.x < agent's IP
```

and in the agent's logs it says:

```
2020-05-13T16:36:33.132-04:00 INFO: http://jenkins.domain.internal/login is not ready: 503 < waiting for Jenkins to join the lb
2020-05-13T16:36:43.749-04:00 May 13, 2020 8:36:43 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
2020-05-13T16:36:43.749-04:00 INFO: WebSocket connection open
2020-05-13T16:36:43.749-04:00 May 13, 2020 8:36:43 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
2020-05-13T16:36:43.749-04:00 INFO: Connected
```

But the agent is showing as offline. I'm at a loss to troubleshoot this. If I delete the agent out of Jenkins then I see a line in the Jenkins log saying that the agent is not recognized.

Comment: Just following this thread! I am also stuck at the same stage. BTW, Did you use the latest version of jenkins 2.217 and above. Also agent.jar version 4.0 or later.

Comment: I did use the latest Jenkins. GSM was right, the agent jar on the docker container is 4.1 and the agent on the Jenkins' agent management page is 4.0. Using the 4.0 agent everything worked out of the box & I no longer have port 50000 open. Woot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that with version inbound-jenkins-agent:4.0.1-1 of the JNLP inbound agent works fine. Other, later versions are having trouble. At least in our environment things started working after using this version.

See this issue: https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-inbound-agent/issues/172

Comment: This is correct, after using the jar that you grab from the Jenkins agent's page it worked, the version that comes with the latest jnlp containers is too new and does not.

Comment: Using the latest (not TLS) Jenkins works now out of the box.